# Can't upgrade rvm on Debian, seems to hang?

Tags: rvm, debian, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade RVM on my Debian server but it doesn't work for some reason. Here's the output of the command `rvm get stable`:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  9979  100  9979    0     0  10276      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
Turning on auto mode.

Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

100 1047k  100 1047k    0     0   438k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  757k

Upgrading the RVM installation in /usr/local/rvm/
  RVM system user group 'rvm' exists, proceeding with installation.
```

After that it doesn't continue. I've been waiting for about an hour already but no luck.

Also tried other methods shown on https://rvm.io/rvm/upgrading/

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check on what the process hangs with:

```
rvm --trace get stable
```

there will be a lot of output but the last lines are important, they will show which command stops execution.

It's quite possible that you have some function / alias redefined which changes meaning of RVM code - as it is loaded directly to your shell, one of most common redefinitions is:

```
: -> "cd .."
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the hint. It gets stuck at this point: `+ /src/rvm/scripts/functions/installer : setup_rvm_path_permissions()  734 > xargs -n1 -0 chmod g+s`

Comment: then you need to check why this command fails - it is not supposed to fail: `find "$rvm_path" -type d -print0 | xargs -n1 -0 chmod g+s`

Comment: Oh, I just let it being stuck there and waited far less then before without the --trace param and it worked! No idea why but it worked, however whenever I run any rvm command it shows me all that --trace stuff. Can I deactivate it somehow?

Comment: Unfortunately not. `rvm reload` results in about 300 lines of output.